# ImportError: cannot import name shared

Tags: python, macos, emscripten

When I try to build, I get error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name shared
```

Here is the full error log:

```
File "/Users/Apple/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.30.0/emconfigure", line 21, in <module>
    from tools import shared
ImportError: cannot import name shared
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Apple/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.30.0/emmake", line 22, in <module>
    from tools import shared
ImportError: cannot import name shared
mv: rename src/ngspice to src/ngspice.bc: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Apple/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.30.0/emcc", line 52, in <module>
    from tools import shared, jsrun, system_libs
ImportError: cannot import name shared
```

Here is how I have installed tools which has name shared:

```
bash-3.2$ pip install tools
Downloading/unpacking tools
  Downloading tools-0.1.9.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/8g/p8wtd8g17z973rpjrz5dx4_h0000gn/T/pip_build_Apple/tools/setup.py) egg_info for package tools

Downloading/unpacking pytils (from tools)
  Downloading pytils-0.3.tar.gz (89kB): 89kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/8g/p8wtd8g17z973rpjrz5dx4_h0000gn/T/pip_build_Apple/pytils/setup.py) egg_info for package pytils

    warning: no files found matching 'README'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /Applications/djangostack-1.7.8-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.7.3-py2.7.egg (from tools)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /Applications/djangostack-1.7.8-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg (from tools)
Installing collected packages: tools, pytils
  Running setup.py install for tools

  Running setup.py install for pytils

    warning: no files found matching 'README'
Successfully installed tools pytils
Cleaning up...
```

Is this problem related to current installation (2.7) for python?

**edit**

```
bash-3.2$ which pip
/Applications/djangostack-1.7.8-0/python/bin/pip
bash-3.2$ which python
/Applications/djangostack-1.7.8-0/python/bin/python
```

**edit 2**

I am trying to compile: `emcc - compiler helper script` which has:

```
import os, sys, shutil, tempfile, subprocess, shlex, time, re, logging
from subprocess import PIPE
from tools import shared, jsrun, system_libs
from tools.shared import Compression, execute, suffix, unsuffixed, unsuffixed_basename, WINDOWS, safe_move
from tools.response_file import read_response_file
```

I am trying to compile c++ library into javascript using Emscripten

**edit 3**

codesnipped above stored at `~/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.30.0/emcc`
my current directory is:

```
$ pwd
/Users/Apple/Documents/projects/myproject/ngspice/release
```

https://github.com/concord-consortium/build-ngspice-js

**edit 4**

If I uninstall tools, here is what I get:

```
File "/Users/Apple/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.30.0/emcc", line 52, in <module>
    from tools import shared, jsrun, system_libs
ImportError: No module named tools
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `tools` does not contain any function or module named `shared`.

Comment: Yep, PYPI package `tools` doesn't have `shared` module/function.

Comment: strange, please check 'edit 2' above

Comment: Quick googling showed, that there is `shared.py` in `tools` directory in `emscripten` project. I have no idea why it fails to import this file. Edit your question, please to reflect what your were trying to do

Comment: I think you should `pip uninstall tools`. You don't need this library. Where is the codesnipped of edit 2 stored? What's your current working directory?

Comment: should I really `pip uninstall tools` ?

Comment: I've tried to pip uninstall tools, please see edit 4